# How to print only the files and directories started with a specific character using 'ls' bash command?

Tags: bash, shell

I have to list every item in /etc that starts with 'a'.

I tried to look for something in the online manual but found nothing.
I'm using the following script:

```
list=$(ls -a /etc);  
for item in $list; do
    echo $item
done
```

Comment: Files in /etc that start with "a" => `/etc/a*` -- See [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in the manual

Comment: [don't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: do you need to (recursively) search subdirectories under `/etc`?

Comment: for printing them you can simply `printf '%s\n' /etc/a*` or `ls -1d /etc/a*`, but don't store the output of those commands in a variable because it's not possible to accurately use it afterwards

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Comment: This would be `ls /etc/a*`, but I don't see why you want to use `ls` in the code you posted.  For looping over them, your approach does not really work anyway (you would have to write something like `for item in /etc/a*`)